# O plugin qTranslate esconde o menu da Homepage

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

No meu site WordPress, tenho o tema [Designy](http://themeforest.net/item/designy-a-design-led-business-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/4625484). Quando no qTranslate se escolhe a opção de ***Hide Content , which is not available for the selected language***, desaparece com o menu da home page e com o slider que está na secção *Homepage item*.

Qual o problema?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que este problema esteja acontecendo por que você está acessando alguma página em que a mesma não esta sendo traduzida pelo qTranslate. Nesses casos o qTranslate informa ao usuário que a página não possui tradução.